# css tabs-changing from absolute to relative positioning

Tags: html, css

Now after several hours, I am still stuck at this problem; I am trying to make this box relatively positioned so that the results do not overlap  my footer. I tried to achieve this via javascript and that did not work and now I am not sure how to make this relatively aligned.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp2kV/1/

I am sure the problem can be solved if I change content from absolute to relative but after that I am not able to align it the same way as now.

This is the part, where I think I need to edit positioning.

```
.content  {
   position: absolute;
    top: 28px;
    left: 0;
    background: #eee;
    right: 81px;
    min-height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: What footer? Why are you using any kind of positioning there anyway? That effect can be achieved by using `display: inline-block` on the menu items, and toggling between `display: block` and `display: none` on the associated content.

Comment: would you please show it on the fiddle, I am not sure if I am doing the same things as you said, as it did not work.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the result contents to be contained inside the DIV area and have a scrollbar at the right side, you can add the following property inside your .content selector. This is if you want the height to stay the same.

```
overflow: auto;
```

But if you want the height to be flexible, then you should implement this approach..

First, remove the height property.

```
<div id="results_1">
    <div style="clear: left; height: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
```

will become

```
<div id="results_1">
    <div style="clear: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
```

Before the **closing tag** of `<div class="content">`, you should add `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`. This will automatically expand the gray container height depending on content.

Maybe what you'll have to do next is have a javascript code to compute height of the contents box then adjust the top margin of your footer via javascript so they won't overlap.

---

I highly suggest just use a jquery plugin instead to create a tabbed box and disregard my solutions. This will solve your positioning problems. The only way you were able to overlap .content boxes is because they are absolutely positioned.. and absolute positioned elements do not add up to the size of their parents. So the moment you change absolute to relative, the tabs will scatter because each tab will expand to the size of their  child elements. You can't achieve tabbed boxes and not overlap the footer with your current approach, unless you use javascript, or apply `overflow: auto;` on the .content selector.

Hope this helps.